# Haskell Environment

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I recently finished the book "learnyouahaskell" and now I would like to apply my acquired knowledge by building a yesod application.

However I am not sure about how to get started.

There seems to be two options on how to set up a yesod project. One is with [Stack](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack), and the other is with cabal sandboxes.

But what are the differences (If any?) and the similarities between them? Does one count as best practice whereas the other doesn't?

The yesod [quickstart](http://www.yesodweb.com/page/quickstart) suggests using stack, is this fine or should I use cabal sanbox?

Comment: well... if the *yesod developers* strongly suggest one of the options, why do you ask us?

Comment: i would like to know the differences between them and if someone has made different/better experiences with one of them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually three different packages that are being talked about here.

1. [`cabal-install`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-install) is the current stable binary to build your applications.
2. [`stack`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/stack) was just released to the public recently. I believe it is trying to replace `cabal-install` as a better, more convenient tool. At the very least, it is showing the Haskell community a different way of something things.
3. [`Cabal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal) is the library that both `cabal-install` and `stack` are based off of.

As for the differences between the first two tools.

`cabal-install` is a mature application used nearly everywhere within the Haskell community (at least in open source, I have no idea what people are doing behind closed doors).

`stack` is still a new (at least to the public) application used in some newer projects. Some more information can be found [here](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/announcing-first-public-beta-stack). But some of the highlights are:

- running `stack build` in a projects directory will install GHC (Haskell compiler) as well as the needed dependencies for the project.
- `stack`, by default, runs off of [stackage](https://www.stackage.org/). Which is a curated version of [hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/). Meaning you can expect the different packages to play nicely with each other. Leading to reproducible builds.
- You can still fall back on hackage should you choose to.

The great thing about these two applications is that they can be used by different people for the same project. If you decide you want to use `cabal-install` with sandboxes, and someone comes along and wants to help with your project, they can just add the files that `stack` needs and they can use `stack` while you continue to use `cabal-install`. Or vice-versa.

[here](https://np.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/3a6p9h/how_stack_lowers_the_barrier_to_open_source/) is one persons experience after using `stack` for the first time. They claim that it is a little bit easier to get started because there are a couple less steps required to get started. If nothing else, people highlight the pros and cons of each tool.

**Note**: I'm still fairly new to Haskell, and have never actually used `stack`. <strike>I've actually been told to stay away from it unless building something in `yesod`</strike>.

**Edit**: As stated in a comment under this answer, I believe I have mis-represented what people have told me about stack. The comments people have given me when I asked if I should switch over to stack were more along the lines of, *If you are comfortable enough using cabal sandboxes, there is no reason to switch over to stack unless you are having issues*.

Comment: I'm curious, who's saying to stay away from stack? What reasons do they give? This is news to me. In addition, [this comparison blog post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/why-is-stack-not-cabal) may be quite useful in understanding things.

Comment: After re-reading my answer, I believe I have mis-represented the comments that people have made to me regarding using stack. I'm going to make an edit to my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks, that attitude makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

The lead developer of Yesod (Michael Snoyman) is actively involved with the Stack tool. So, I would recommend you to set up Yesod with Stack. Also, Yesod has a quite a complex set of dependencies and using Stackage as the default curated source, helps very much in the installation process (which Stack takes care of by default).

Also [read this post](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/06/why-is-stack-not-cabal) for understanding the differences of Stack from cabal.